# How to double integrate with +inf?

Tags: r, integral, numerical-integration

So i have this code in R that tries to double integrate a function f(x,y) using **integral2**, where one domain is (0.5 , +inf), but **integral2** doesn't support it (because of that infinite). My question is: do you know a way to make it work?

```
 fprob8 <- function(a , b)
{
  f <- function(x , y)
  {
    densGamma <- function(x)
    {
      numitor <- b ^ a * fgam(a)
      numarator <- x ^ (a - 1) * exp(-x / b)
      return (numarator / numitor)
    }

    densBeta <- function(x)
    {
      numitor <- fbet(a , b)
      numarator <- (1 - x) ^ (b - 1) * x ^ (a - 1)
      return (numarator/numitor)
    }

    return (densGamma(x) * densBeta(y)) 
  }

  ymin <- function(x) # limita superioara pentru cea de-a doua integrala
  {
    return (min(x - 0.5),1)
  }

  I <- integral2(f, 0.5 , Inf , ymin , 1)
  return(I)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand because ymin=1 when x > 1.5

Comment: Ye, finally i made it trough ( made that integral a sum of 2 integrals). Anyway, thanks for your help, I used pcubature for an integral with +Inf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `cubature` package. It evaluates multiple integrals, allowing infinite bounds.

Here is an example:

```
library(cubature)
f <- function(x) exp(-x[1]-x[2])
pcubature(f, c(0,0), c(Inf,Inf))$integral
# 1

library(pracma)
f2 <- function(x,y) f(c(x,y))
integral2(f2, 0, 1000, 0, 1000, vectorized = FALSE)$Q
# 1
```

Comment: The domain of the second integral can depend of x? I want to implement this: pcubature (f2 , c(0 , min(x - 0.5,1)) , c ( Inf , 1))

Comment: @AndreiManolache No sorry, I missed that. Maybe you could try a change of variables.